# How to scan a file/github against a keyword.txt?

Tags: python

I have a keywords.csv

| Keyword | Comment |
| --- | --- |
| public stake | double check |
| _return | this will cause a panic! |
| _stake |  |
| this is a pattern |  |

And I want to use those keywords to scan a file/rawgithub doc.

The script should go check each line in keywords.csv and print out if it matches the word/s going through line by line of the file to be scanned. note, that it should loosely match.

*Example: I know the stake is very public.*

This should match with *public stake*

Also, I want it to print out the line number and comment from table if possible, but I'm totally stuck

what I have so far

```
from string import punctuation

with open('test.txt', 'r') as f1, open('keywords.csv') as f2:
    st = set(map(str.rstrip, f2))
    for line in f1:
        if any(word.lower().strip(punctuation) in st for word in line.split()):
            print(line)
```

Comment: what do `_return` and `_stake` represent in the `keywords.txt` file ?

Comment: just patterns to scan the target for

Comment: @D.L modified the question to make it more clear

Answer (score 0):

You should use `import csv` for working with csv files.

Besides that you can simply check if the key is in the line.

```py
import csv

with open('test.txt', 'r') as f1, open('keywords.csv', 'r') as f2:
    st = csv.reader(f2, delimiter=';')
    keywords = [item[0] for item in st][1:]
    
    for line in f1:
        for keyword in map(str.split, keywords):
            if all([key in line for key in keyword]):
                print(line)
```